# What is the advantage of not having pooling layers in between convolutions in this context?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolution, conv-neural-network

In the context of a convolutional neural network designed to extract DNA motifs, why would one stack convolution layers without max pooling functions in between?

Here's the context in which this architecture appears.

```
self.model = Sequential()
assert len(num_filters) == len(conv_width)
for i, (nb_filter, nb_col) in enumerate(zip(num_filters, conv_width)):
    conv_height = 4 if i == 0 else 1
    self.model.add(Convolution2D(
        nb_filter=nb_filter, nb_row=conv_height,
        nb_col=nb_col, activation='linear',
        init='he_normal', input_shape=self.input_shape,
        W_regularizer=l1(L1), b_regularizer=l1(L1)))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(Dropout(dropout))
self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, pool_width)))
```

Comment: If you do not have any activation functions, the network is a stack of multiple linear function and is, therefore, a linear function. This network will not be very powerful as it can only represent linear functions. Why this is done, I am not sure.

Comment: There is one layer of activation layer, followed by a layer of max pooling, but both come after the convolution layers. My question is why do the convolution layers come one after another as opposed to being separated by activation or pooling layers. @PankajDaga

Comment: Not sure without seeing soem context or a paer. The signal passing through those layers will only be linearly transformed. `Why` it is being done would just be speculation on my part without more details.

Comment: please provide link to the source of such architecture.

Comment: https://github.com/kundajelab/dragonn/blob/e6a7f7f39c6b9e08f2ac541ddd10fb19e2c0ba04/dragonn/models.py @lejlot

Comment: this code has activations between convolutions (line :120)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code provided **does** use activations between convolutions

```
self.model = Sequential()
assert len(num_filters) == len(conv_width)
for i, (nb_filter, nb_col) in enumerate(zip(num_filters, conv_width)):
    conv_height = 4 if i == 0 else 1
    self.model.add(Convolution2D(
        nb_filter=nb_filter, nb_row=conv_height,
        nb_col=nb_col, activation='linear',
        init='he_normal', input_shape=self.input_shape,
        W_regularizer=l1(L1), b_regularizer=l1(L1)))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu')) #  <--------------------- ACTIVATION
    self.model.add(Dropout(dropout))
self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, pool_width)))
```

resulting model is something like

```
conv -- relu -- dropout -- conv -- relu -- dropout -- ... -- max pool
```

why they put activation separately instead of specyfing "activation" inside conv itself? No idea, looks like an odd implementation decision, but from practical point of view the

```
self.model.add(Convolution2D(
        nb_filter=nb_filter, nb_row=conv_height,
        nb_col=nb_col, activation='linear',
        init='he_normal', input_shape=self.input_shape,
        W_regularizer=l1(L1), b_regularizer=l1(L1)))
self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

and

```
self.model.add(Convolution2D(
        nb_filter=nb_filter, nb_row=conv_height,
        nb_col=nb_col, activation='relu',
        init='he_normal', input_shape=self.input_shape,
        W_regularizer=l1(L1), b_regularizer=l1(L1)))
```

are **equivalent**.

Comment: you do not always need max pooling at all, each such operation significantly reduces resolution of the image, thus it is added **if needed**, not **by default**. In terms of FCN layer - it is there, you are clearly not reading the code in detail, look at line 130.

Answer (score 3):

For a given input dimension you can only reduce spatial dimensions (typically by factor of 2 each time) so many times before you arrive at a 1x1 output dimension that can't be reduced any more! Hence, for a deep net you have no choice but to have groups of layers (convolutions) without dimensionality reduction, separated by layers that do dimensionality reduction. So, it's not a matter of there being any advantage to having convolutional layers without max pooling in between, but rather than you can only have so many total max pooling layers for a given input size.

Note that the only function of max pooling as used here is dimensionality reduction - there's no other benefit to it. In fact, more modern all-convolutional architectures such as ResNet-50 don't use max pooling (except at the input), and instead use stride 2 convolutions to gradually reduce dimensions.